# Does the phrase "まるで爪のようだと鬼ホミコーシスから食べ物視される" have a sense in Japanese?

Tags: translation

"鬼ホミコーシス" is a kind of wordplay on nail disease onychomycosis. I try to write "Onychomycosis looks at (and regards) your nails as if it's a food" in Japanese.
There is a meme in russian internet subculture. It is a photo of smbd. with scornful or contemptuous look and a caption "He/She looks at (and regards) you as if you are s... (カス)"

Answer (score 3):

Your suggestion is at least "grammatical", but its meaning is probably not what you want.

> まるで爪のようだと鬼ホミコーシスから食べ物視される。
> [Someone/Somebody] is seen and regarded as food by oni-chomycosis as if it/he/she were nails.

- That nail disease is almost always called 爪白癬【つめはくせん】 or 爪の水虫【みずむし】 in Japanese, so it's very likely that your pun will not be understood (unless your audience is dermatologists). Its pathogen is 白癬菌【はくせんきん】 (jargon) or 水虫菌【みずむしきん】 (casual).
- まるで爪のようだ means "it looks as if it/he/she were a nail".
- I don't know that Russian meme, but it's perhaps natural to use the ている form and avoid passive voice.

With a microscopic picture of "oni-chomycosis", a caption like these may work:

- 水虫菌にはお前の爪が食べ物に見えている
- 水虫菌がお前の爪を食べ物だと思いながら見ている
- 水虫菌にお前の爪は餌だと思われている